# How to click on the Sign in element with GitHub page https://github.com/ using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use Selenium for python to click on the sign in link at the top of github. I've tried using `find_element_by_link_text()` but i get a *NoSuchElementException*. I then tried using `find_element_by_xpath()` and I got an *ElementNotinteractableException*. Here is the code for the first:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://github.com')

signin = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in')
signin.click()
```

and here's the code for the second.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://github.com')

signin_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]')
signin_link.click()
```

I even tried `find_element_by_css_selector()` but also got an *ElementNotInteractableException*. I don't understand what's going wrong. I don't feel like putting in the html, but if you go to github, it's just the sign in link at the very top right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out to pass chromedriver path. Try this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
```

Also, If you want to go to the login page, then I would recommend avoiding the long way root. What I mean is, the following code should directly take you to the login page:

```
browser.get('https://github.com/login')
```

However, if you must know, how else you can click that element, try looping over "href" elements:

```
for el in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
    if "/login" in el.get_attribute('href'):
        el.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use following locator strtegies.

**LINK_TEXT**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://github.com')
signin =WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Sign in")))
signin.click()
```

**XPATH**:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://github.com')
signin =WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@href='/login']")))
signin.click()
```

**CSS Selector:**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://github.com')
signin =WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[href='/login']")))
signin.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the <kbd>Sign in</kbd> element at the top right corner of GitHub page https://github.com/ using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sign"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(., 'Sign')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```